# Why a trigonometric function doesn't satisfy a polynomial equation?

Tags: functions, transcendental-equations

Why can't I have a trigonometric function as an input to a polynomial equation?

Comment: You're title and question seem to be asking different things

Comment: Now it's okay :)

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial has a finite number of zeros, trigonometric functions typically inifite many.